# How to use different tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a pretty regular project structure... my main tsconfig.json is at the root directory of my project and I have no issue with this. But when I try to use a different one (/scripts/tsconfig.json) for production, I have issues. `tsc -p scripts/tsconfig.json` doesn't do anything, and there are no error messages. I am using TypeScript 1.8.10. Here is my scripts/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/js",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
        "../src/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

What else am I missing? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using typescript 2?

Comment: As far as I know `include` supported only from *2*. Try to use `files` or `exclude` instead.